# How to dynamically loop getJson data result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use jQuery $.getJSON to get data from API that return json data in multiple level. The one of the level is dynamic and I want to use varible to access that. Here's the example of result:

```
{
    "status" : "200",
    "result" : {
        "DYNAMIC_DATA_1" : {
            "name" : "Johny",
            "age" : "20"
        },
        "DYNAMIC_DATA_2" : {
            "name" : "Jenny",
            "age" : "25"
        }
    }
}
```

from my example above, the "DYNAMIC_DATA_1" and "DYNAMIC_DATA_2" is actually a unique id.

Here is my code to request the json data:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('/api/username?id='+DYNAMIC_USER_ID, function(data) {
        console.log(data.result.DYNAMIC_DATA.name);
    });
});
```

I want to dynamically loop the `data.result.the-id/key` to get each `name` value.

Comment: Aren't you searching for `console.log(data.result.DYNAMIC_DATA_1.name);`? The key `DYNAMIC_DATA` does not exist.

Comment: They're not "dynamic variables", they're just "object keys".  Google that and get back to us.

Comment: @Paul I want to display all the individual name. So my goal is to use variable in data.result.VARIABLE_HERE.name to display for example the name "Johny".

Comment: I mean I want to reuse the DYNAMIC_USER_ID to display names

Comment: @PixelDsign I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this straight forward way **:**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "status" : "200",
    "result" : {
        "DYNAMIC_DATA_1" : {
            "name" : "Johny",
            "age" : "20"
        },
        "DYNAMIC_DATA_2" : {
            "name" : "Jenny",
            "age" : "25"
        }
    }
};

var dynamicKeys = Object.keys(jsonObj.result);

dynamicKeys.map(item => {
  console.log(jsonObj.result[item].name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With a simple loop you can iterate through your *data.result*, no matter their actual key name, or in your case *unique id*, and here is a few solutions you can use within your `getJSON` function, e.g..

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('/api/username?id='+DYNAMIC_USER_ID, function(data) {
        $.each( data.result, function( key, value ) {
            console.log("Name:", value.name, "(ID/Key is " + key + ")");
        });    
    });
});
```

Stack snippet

```js
var data = {
    "status" : "200",
    "result" : {
        "DYNAMIC_DATA_1" : {
            "name" : "Johny",
            "age" : "20"
        },
        "OTHER_DYNAMIC_DATA_WORKS_TOO" : {
            "name" : "Jenny",
            "age" : "25"
        }
    }
}

//jQuery each
console.log("jQuery each");
$.each( data.result, function( key, value ) {
    console.log("Name:", value.name, "(ID/Key is " + key + ")");
});

//js for-in
console.log("js for-in");
for (var key in data.result) {
    console.log("Name:", data.result[key].name, "(ID/Key is " + key + ")");
}

//js forEach
console.log("js forEach");
Object.keys(data.result).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log("Name:", data.result[key].name, "(ID/Key is " + key + ")");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```